# Excel Power Query Group by

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a table with 2 columns and some rows, I would like to group each distinct rows and different values into new columns.

I am a beginner in Power Query, I know the answer in VBA but I need it in Power Query.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"letters"}, {{"data", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type), type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"group a", "Index"}, {"group a", "Index"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded data", {{"Index", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded data", {{"Index", type text}}, "en-US")[Index]), "Index", "group a", List.Sum)
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]

The trick above is to right click letters column, group by, use operation All Rows

then in formula bar replace

```
each _, type table [letters=text, group a=number]}})
```

with

```
each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type), type table }})
```

Expand the columns using the arrows atop the column, select letter column, and pivot